# How to deploy NuxtJS (2) on Jelastic?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, jelastic

I can't figure out how to deploy NuxtJS to [Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/) simply.

Can I just use a nodeJS node or do I also need a Nginx node to manage the reverse proxy for example?

My backend (API) is made with spring-boot.

Below is the image of my two nodes for the moment. I can easily put in production my spring-boot app since it is a .war archive

But for NuxtJS, how can I deploy my app and execute the necessary commands (cg. npm install, nuxt generate, etc.)?

[image]

Would anyone be willing to answer in the form of a mini-tutorial to do this correctly please?

Comment: Hi, somebody would be glad to have the answer of how you achieved to make this one work.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell because it's not really a well known platform and I don't really want to create myself an account there just to debug it.

Meanwhile, this [Nuxt page](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments) does have a link regarding several deployments. Here, since you went for the Node.js path, I guess that you need to have your app as SSR (`ssr: true` and `target: 'server'`). More common ones would be [Heroku](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/heroku) or [DigitalOcean](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/digital-ocean).
You could probably look for them both and see what are the main similar things and do kind of a mix.

Otherwise, if you went SSG (`ssr: true` and `target: 'static'`), you could go to simpler and more well known platform like Netlify, Vercel, Surge etc...

---

Also, maybe looking for all the same answers with the [jelastic](/questions/tagged/jelastic) tag could maybe provide you with some additional tips!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I can't go through anything other than Jelastic so that's the point of my question. I may have succeeded something, but now I have a problem with node-gyp. It looks like it needs python >= 3.6, but only python 2.7 is available in the container.

Comment: @Jedupont if you cannot move elsewhere and you need a specific version that is not available on your VPS provider, there is no solution: you're basically stuck with what's available.

Comment: I was able to make it work pretty easily. I will reply with the solution here soon.

Comment: @Jedupont - are you able to share your solution? I'm still struggling with this. Thanks for any help!